Cant get rid of black borders!
I'm trying to create a scene using a model from a game but I can't get rid of these black borders and edges, it's like this for almost every other model I try. I tried connecting the alpha nodes together and changing the blend mode to alpha clip but it only works for some but not all, Im still new to blender so I'm not sure what to do.

In Eevee (and if you are in Material preview, either in Eevee or Cycles) you need to go into the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend

Nope, that didn't change anything unfortunately

or in the Render panel > Light Paths, increase the Transparent value, if it still doesn't work please share your file

Should I email you the file? Or can I just send a link?

use a platform like workupload and share the link

Here ya go https://workupload.com/archive/82ZM5Ctwdq

Hello you haven't shared the images, could you please share only one object (a tree) and make sure that the image is packed (File > External Data > Pack Resources)?

Like this? https://workupload.com/archive/YgaBBbATSN Sorry If I didnt do it right.

The material you have selected in the Shader Editor is not the one that is assigned to the tree, the one that is assigned is called stg201_p23.gno2, select it and plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture into the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF, also choose Blend Mode > Alpha Blend:


Hey it worked! Thanks a ton, this will help me out a lot in the future!
